# Get the time in ms for which a view was opened for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a List view and a ViewPager with few items in list.

List:
A
B
C
...(n)

ViewPager:

A <-swipe-> B <-swipe-> C... (n)

I want to get time in ms the user spent on each view (A/B/C) before swiping left/right on the next view or going back to list view.

Any hint or pointers help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using viewpagers OnPageChangeListener,
get the default time `mAStartTime` when user starts the app (this is the time user started in view A, when ever a page is changed in onPageChangeListener get the current page `mCurrentView` and current time `mAEndTime`  which is also the starting time for `mCurrentView` view.
By tracking two time, start time and end time you will be able to get the desired effect.

Comment: I will try that out but I think I wont be able to get time spent in one scenario using OnPageChangeListener i.e 
user clicks `itemB` from the list --> views itemB --> goes back to list. 
so in this case, how would I get time spent by user on itemB?